# After xcode build step, why is DerivedData Build/Products empty?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I'm using TeamCity to build an iOS app, but I'm getting this error:

> error: Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory : '/Users/zzzzz/TeamCity/buildAgent/Work/zzzzzzzzzzz/platforms/ios/DerivedData/myApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.app'

I know the DerivedData folder gets populated during the build, but what specifies what to put in the Products folder? Is this part of the .xcodeproj file?

We recently changed to xcode 6, not sure if that has changed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to specify the DerivedData folder location:**

From the Xcode menu, choose Preferences - > Locations  > Advanced.

My issue was caused by the TeamCity build expecting a legacy location but Xcode was using the default DerivedData folder location.

More info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-locations_preferences/Build/Build.html